# Low fps on higher resolution video file input on OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, face-detection, dlib

I am trying to blur the faces using dlib face detector and open cv. The code works fine when giving input from a webcam but it gives low fps when I give 720p or 1080p video file as input. My end goal is to blur the faces when the video file with any resolution is given to the code.

I have tried reducing the frame size using "cap.set()".But it isn't working. Any help will be appreciated.
[output frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWSa6.png)

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to reduce the resolution of higher quality video if your code already works with lower resolution video? If so, then maybe you could try something like the following code from [opencv.org](https://answers.opencv.org/question/139138/how-to-resize-frames-from-video-with-aspect-ratio/):

```
import cv2
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('myvid2.mp4')
success,image = vidcap.read()
count = 0;
print "I am in success"
while success:
    success,image = vidcap.read()
    resized = cv2.resize(image, fx=0.5, fy=0.5, interpolation = cv2.INTER_LINEAR) 
    cv2.imwrite("%03d.jpg" % count, resize)     
    if cv2.waitKey(10) == 27:                     
        break
    count += 1
```

That should halve the resolution of the video. And you can reduce the resolution further by changing the 0.5 parameters in cv2.resize() to something even smaller.

Comment: Is there any way to input the video in any resolution, blur the face and save it to new video file. Please let me know if there's any way.

Comment: @YashrajNigam Is there something wrong with reducing the resolution before you find and blur the faces? I'm afraid that I'm not all that familiar with opencv so I wouldn't know of any other way of doing it.

Comment: Thank you Bob for your suggestions I have just save the output to the new video file and it works fine.

Comment: @YashrajNigam Okay good to hear, feel free to accept the answer then if you're satisfied with it...